# In a differential equation, is recursion allowed?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recursion

Take the following ordinary differential equations.

$$y'(x^2) + y(x) = x$$

$$y''(y'(y(x))) = x^{x^x}$$

$$y''(5) + y(x) = x$$

Is there anything wrong with any of these as differential equations? I know that nonlinear equations can result from terms consisting of various derivatives of $y$ multiplied together. For instance: $y(x)y'(x) = x$. However, these seem almost recursive. I do not know whether or not they are valid.

Comment: Definitely not linear in the form they are currently in (Except the third, which can be solved by letting y"(5) be a constant). I don't see why it wouldn't be "valid" though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original post, they were not valid for a somewhat technical reason. Either you treat $y$ as a function, in which case $y'$ and $y''$ are both functions as well, or you treat $y$ as a **variable** and not a function. However, it was relatively obvious what you actually meant, and indeed it is very clear in your current version of the question. I'll leave my original explanation of that specific issue in the next section.

---

In the former case, "$y$" does **not** represent a real/complex number and so your differential equations should have been written:

> $y'(x^2)+y\color{red}{(x)} = x$.
>
> $y''(y'(y\color{red}{(x)})) = x^{x^x}$.
>
> $y''(5) + y\color{red}{(x)} = x$.

In the latter case, where $x,y$ are both variables varying with respect to some parameter (which is a common interpretation in classical mechanics), your equations would mean a totally different thing:

> $y' \times x^2 + y = x$.
>
> $y'' \times y' \times y = x^{x^x}$.
>
> $5 \times y'' + y = x$.

It is clearly crucial to know which interpretation is used, and also crucial to be consistent. It is certain that your example of "a nonlinear equation resulting from terms consisting of various derivatives of y multiplied together" uses the second interpretation:

> $y \times y' = x$, where $x,y$ are variables.

Which if written using the former notation would be:

> $y(x) \times y'(x) = x$, where $y$ is a function.

---

As I implied in my original post, you are justified in calling your equations differential equations.

It is true that the most commonly known differential equations generally relate variables and their instantaneous derivatives, and so there is no need of an explicit symbol for the parameter (usually time). This is in fact the reason for the second notation shown above.

However, I can come up with scenarios where there is a natural necessity for differential equations that relate variables to derivatives at other points in time. For example, homeostatic mechanisms have feedback loops that maintain some desirable state, such as core body temperature. But these mechanism kick in after some lag, so the differential equations to model them will have to take that into account to be accurate.

Comment: "differential equations that relate variables to derivatives at other points in time." - these are often modeled as "delay differential equations" (DDEs), and are a lot less complicated than the OP's proposal.

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician: Yes that's for sure. My example might certainly be well approximated by a 'delay' differential equation, and even if there is a real-world system that is described by more complicated differential equations, it is nigh impossible to have something like $x^x$.

Comment: Since some people are misreading this answer, the equations in the question are justifiably called differential equations, but are **certainly not** ODEs, because they are not expressed in the form of an ODE, namely "$f(x,y,D_x(y),{D_x}^2(y),\cdots,{D_x}^k(y)) = 0$" for some function $f : \mathbb{R}^{k+1} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$, where $D_x = \frac{d}{dx}$. This is essentially a precise version of the definition given on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation).

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: Yes; I believe I saw the first and third instance of the question in your post (namely in the title and just before the question mark), and missed that you had called them ODEs. I hope it's all clear now and you know how to define rigorously the notion of other weird kinds of differential equations that don't fall into the usual categories. =)

Answer (score 0):

They are "valid".  The first two are compositions of functions.  The last one is a little weird because $y''(5)$ is a constant $\Rightarrow$ $x-y$ is a constant $\Rightarrow$ is the equation of a line $\Rightarrow$ $y''=0$.  The second one probably has no hope of being solved.

Comment: Depends on your definition of "valid." None of them appear to be well-posed (in the sense of Hadamard).

Comment: @MichaelLee: In fact all three examples are internally inconsistent in their notation and hence cannot be reasonably considered valid...